# pass data of selected list element with jQueryMobile/HTML

Tags: jquery, list, select, parameters

I'm building a list, where you can choose one of the items and that brings you to another page with details about the selected element.

So I need to know which element was selected, to build the detail-page.

I'm building my list like this:

```
$.getJSON("fakultaeten.js",function(data)
        {
            var list = $('#taskList');
            $.each(data.fakultaeten, function(key,value)
            {
                var mother = "<li id='first'>"+value.name+"<ul>";
                $.each(value.institut, function(key1, value1)
                {
                     var son="<li id='second' data-param='"+value1+"'><a  href='#detail'>"+value1+"/a></li>";           
                    mother+=son;                    
                });
                mother+="</ul></li>";
                list.append(mother);  
            });
            list.listview("refresh");
            return false; 

        });
```

And then I try to detect when a user clicks on a list item:

```
$("#second").on("click",function(event) {
                        console.log($(this).text())
                })
```

But this doesn't work. Although it works for the #first list element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is beacuse **ID should always be unique**...you have more that one elements with the same id... you cannot have multiple elements with the same id which is invalid though it works but might get you in big problems like the problem you are facing it now.(only the first element with that id being called).

change your `second` id to class and use class selector

```
 var son="<li class='second' data-param='"+value1+"'><a  href='#detail'>"+value1+"/a></li>";
```

**jquery**

```
 $("ul").on("click",'.second',function(event) {
         console.log($(this).text())
 })
```

notice, the `on()`, you should delegate it to the closest static parent which i think is `ul` here else you can delegate it to document

```
 $(document).on("click",'.second',function(event) {
   ...
```

however it is recommended to use the closest static parent that is present in the document.